# what's the host port number when we use accept() and connect() in C socket programming

Tags: c, sockets

the [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html) explains the accept() as follows:

What's going to happen is this: someone far far away will try to connect() to your machine on a port that you are listen()ing on. Their connection will be queued up waiting to be accept()ed. You call accept() and you tell it to get the pending connection. It'll return to you a **brand new socket file descriptor** to use for this single connection!

but how do we know the port number of the "brand new socket"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the accepted `SOCKET` to `getsockname()` to retreive its local IP/Port, and to `getpeername()` to retreive its remote IP/Port.

Comment: thank you, i tried getsockname(). But it seems the port of the "brand new socket" is as same as the port of the original listening socket. Do you know why it is?

Comment: @zwx That's how connection oriented sockets work. The local port is the one the client connected to, and that is your "server" port.

Answer (score 1):

I think getpeername will return this information

Answer (score 1):

From the GNU docs on accept.

```
                newfd = accept (sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &clientname, &size);
                if (newfd < 0) {
                    perror ("accept");
                    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
```

In the accept sockaddr.in struc, you find the local port.

```
                fprintf (stderr, "Server: connect from host %s, port %hd.\n",
                    inet_ntoa (clientname.sin_addr),
                    ntohs (clientname.sin_port));
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not assign a new port. The accepted socket uses the same port as the listening socket.